# Dont enforce one of conditions in MySQL Query.

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
**people**
ID First Last Email        WageID  ShiftID
1 john Smith jhn@mail.com    2       3
2 sara doe   sar@mail.com    1         <----- no number



**wages**
ID Wage
1 300
2 500
3 800



**shifts**
ID Shift
1 day
2 night
3 half
```

I need to make one query for to get info from all tables
I have:

```
SELECT people.ID people.First people.Last people.Email wages.Wage, shifts.Shift 
FROM people, wages, shifts 
WHERE people.wageID = wages.ID
AND people.shiftID = shifts.ID
```

Problem is that because "Sara Doe" does not have shift id specified it does not show her i think because of last like of select query is there way to make working query to show all people without altering tables?

If i try `OR people.shiftID = shifts.ID` it still dont show her

Answer (score 3):

You should use [OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html) for this

```
SELECT people.ID, people.First, people.Last, people.Email, wages.Wage, 
shifts.Shift FROM people
JOIN wages ON people.wageID = wages.ID
OUTER JOIN shifts ON people.shiftID = shifts.ID
```

Comment: Thanks,

at line JOIN wages ON people.wageID = wages.IDAND you forgot OUTER or its how it supposed to be?

Comment: It's not forgotten, it's just a different type of JOIN (INNER JOIN). And remove the "AND" from wages.IDAND.

Comment: Could you explain why we need to use inner join rather than outer ?

Comment: Basically it's because there exists a primary key in 'wages' for each corresponding foreign key in 'people'. This is not true for 'shifts'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some **left joins** :

```
select people.ID people.First people.Last people.Email wages.Wage, shifts.Shift
from people
    left join wages on wages.ID = people.WageID
    left join shifts on shifts.ID = people.ShiftID
```